# Kotlin declaration signature clash?

Tags: generics, kotlin, constructor, jvm, bytecode

I know this has been asked before but the solutions given do not apply here.

The code in question is a simple class:

```
class BitString(bits: List<Bit>) {
    constructor(bits: List<Number>): this(bits.map(::Bit))
    constructor(bits: List<Boolean>): this(bits.map(::Bit))

    var bits = bits

}
```

`Bit` is a class implemented by me.

However I get the familiar:

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V):
    constructor BitString(bits: List<Bit>) defined in BitString
    constructor BitString(bits: List<Boolean>) defined in BitString
    constructor BitString(bits: List<Number>) defined in BitString
```

My guess is that the generated bytecode does not differentiate between the different specialized lists, which seems like something that should be a priority to fix but... apparently it's not.

My question is how should I get this code to work and preferably look nice? The point is that it should take a `List` of either `Bit`, `Number` or `Boolean` so the class can be constructed from a wide range of collections.

Comment: Have a look at Type Erasure. That's how generics work in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the look and feel of the constructor you can combine the [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) with the [`invoke`-operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke):

```
class BitString(val bits: List<Bit>) {
  companion object {
    @JvmName("fromNumbers")
    operator fun invoke(bits : List<Number>) = BitString(bits.map(::Bit))
    @JvmName("fromBooleans")
    operator fun invoke(bits : List<Boolean>) = BitString(bits.map(::Bit))
  }
}
```

Constructing the `BitString` will then look as familiar as calling a constructor:

```
BitString(yourNumberList) // calls fromNumbers
BitString(listOf(true, false)) // calls fromBooleans
BitString(listOf(Bit(...))) // the actual constructor
```

Comment: This is amazing! I knew about `JvmName` but would never have thought to use it like this!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a companion object's methods, e.g.

```
companion object {

fun fromBools(bits:List<Boolean>) = BitString(bits.map(::Bit))

}
```

then call it like this:

```
BitString.fromBools(bits)
```

That's probably one way around this issue.